# C# compare native type with nullable type (Int32 with Int32?)

Tags: c#, generics, types, nullable

Is there a way to compare nullable and non-nullable generics in C#?

For example:

```
public void function<T>()
{
    Type t = sqlreader.GetValue(pos).GetType();
}
```

where `t` is of type `Int32` and `T` is of type `Nullable<Int32>`.

How can we compare `t` and `T` such that it returns `true`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t)`.
If `t` is a `Nullable<X>`, this will return `typeof(X)`; otherwise, it will return `null`.

Therefore, you can write

```
t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) ?? t;
Type bigT = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) ?? typeof(T);

if (t == bigT)
```

Answer (score 8):

It's fairly unclear what you're trying to do, but you *may* be able to just use [`Nullable.getUnderlyingType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype.aspx):

```
if (t == Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)))
```